# Toss a coin $n$ times (independently) , $P(toss=head)=p, P(toss=tail)=1-p$. Denote $X_n=$sum of successive pairs with the same result.

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Toss a coin $n$ times (independently) , $P(toss=head)=p, P(toss=tail)=1-p$.

Denote $X_n=$sum of successive pairs with the same result.

An example: for THHTTTH $X_7=3$ since we have 3 successive pairs with the same result (HH,TT,TT).

$(a).$ Find $E[X_n]$

$(b).$ Find $Var(X_n)$

My solution:

Denote $X_{i}=\begin{cases}
1 & ,\text{get the same result as the previous toss}\\
0 & ,\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

$E[X_n]=\sum_{i=1}^nX_iP=\sum_{i=1}^n1\cdot P(X_i=1)+0\cdot P(X_i=0)=\sum_{i=1}^n(1-p)^2+p^2=(1-p)^2+p^2\sum_{i=1}^n1=((1-p)^2+p^2)n$

$Var(X_n)=E[X^2_n]-E[X_n]^2=((1-p)^2+p^2)n-(((1-p)^2+p^2)n)^2$ (since $E[X^2_n]=E[X_n]$).

Is my solution correct ?

I will be grateful for feedback.

Thanks !

Comment: Not sure what $X_n$ is.  In your example, you have $7$ coin tosses but you refer to $X_6$.  Should that have been $X_7$?

Comment: @lulu Sorry , It is 7 , fixed.

Comment: Regardless of that, why should $E[X_n^2]=E[X_n]$?  $X_n$ is a sum of indicator functions and $X_n^2$ will pick up cross terms.

Comment: Ok, but you appear to use $X_n$ to also refer to the pairwise indicator variables.  It's very confusing.  And your sum over the pairwise indicator expectations shouldn't run from $0$ to $n$.  There are only $n-1$ pairs, after all.

Comment: @lulu you are right $E[X_i]=E[X_i^2]$ , I was confused , How can I get $E[X^2_n]$ please ?

Comment: There's a lot of carelessness here.  I suggesting fixing $n$, say $n=3$, and working it out explicitly.  There are only $8$ paths so the direct computation is manageable.  That way you can test whatever formula you eventually get.  Worth doing $n=2$ of course, but there are too few paths, and no possible cross terms, so I think it won't be very useful. $n=4$ would help, and $16$ paths isn't all that bad.

Comment: Should say:  the overall approach is absolutely fine.  I'd say it's optimal.  Just write it all out clearly and it should work.

Comment: Honestly, I don't get why the beginning of my solution isn't correct

Comment: To your question, in the comment, To avoid the confusion your notation causes, let $X$ be the number of matching pairs, and then $X_i$ can still be the indicator for the $i^{th}$ pair.  Then $X=(X_1+\cdots +X_{n-1})$.  Square to get $X^2=X_1+\cdots +X_{n-1}+\sum_{i\neq j}X_iX_j$. Where we have used your remark that $X_i=X_i^2$ for indicator variables.

Comment: I already told you that you summation is wrong.  Please work examples for small $n$.  That is far and away the best way to trap careless errors.  Note that for $n=1$ your formula for the expectation is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb E(X_n)=((1-p)^2+p^2)(n-1)$ since there are $n-1$ consecutive pairs and each pair has $(1-p)^2+p^2$ probability to have same result. This is not $((1-p)^2+p^2)n$, since the indices does NOT modulo $n$.

Denote $Y_i$ be the random variable if $i$th and $i+1$th coin are same.

$Var(X_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}Var(Y_i)+2\sum_{1\le i<j\le n-1}Cov(Y_i,Y_j)$

Notice that $Var(Y_i)=\mathbb P(Y_i=1)(1-P(Y_i=1))=2p(1-p)((1-p)^2+p^2)$

For $j-i\ge 2$ we have $Cov(Y_i,Y_j)=0$.

Also we have $Cov(Y_i,Y_{i+1})=\mathbb P(Y_i=Y_{i+1}=1)-P(Y_i=1)P(Y_{i+1}=1)=(p^3+(1-p)^3)-((1-p)^2+p^2)^2=p(1-p)(2p-1)^2$

Therefore, we have
$$Var(X_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}Var(Y_i)+2\sum_{1\le i<j\le n-1}Cov(Y_i,Y_j)=2p(1-p)((1-p)^2+p^2)(n-1)+p(1-p)(2p-1)^2(n-2)=p(1-p)((8p^2-8p+3)n-12p^2+12p-4)$$